# Java,how could I get the last characters via regex?

Tags: java, regex

Java,how could I get the last characters via regex?
for instance, a string like "abcdefff",I'd like to find out "efff" or "ff"....

Comment: Well, which one is it?

Comment: Do you want the trailing chars that are all the same? Like "zzzz" from "abczacbzzzz"?

Answer (score 6):

If you want the last `n` characters of a string, use `substring()`.

```
String lastChars = str.substring(str.length() - 3);
```

If you must match only a single character, use `Pattern` with the regex `n{3}$`.

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("n{3}$");
Matcher matches = regex.matcher(str);
```

Generally, you'd only use a regex if the other string methods would become too unwieldy. If you simply want to grab the last *any* characters, I'd always use `substring()`, as to me, it's clearer to parse mentally.

Comment: Can you tell since when `substring()` works with negative numbers? Just tried `"abcdef".substring(-3)` with jdk 1.6 and got `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3`.

Comment: Maybe it cannot be with negative,while it seems correct to use string.substring(string.length-3).

Comment: Might have to do that, been in JavaScript world too much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way too

```
    String str="abcdefff";
    if(str.length()>2){
    System.out.println(str.substring(str.length()-2));
    }else{
    System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Comment: Or maybe `System.out.println((str.length() < 2) ? str : str.substring(str.length()-2));`  You do have to think about what you want if your string is too short, unless you're happy with exceptions being thrown every which way.